# c++ pass two dimentional vector to function

Tags: c++, vector

I need to pass two dimentional vector to my function. I tried to do it by passing iterator to the begining of the array. But the error occured.

```
using namespace std;

displayArrays(vector< vector< int > >::iterator map_b, vector< int >::iterator row_b, int n, int o){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            cout << *map_b + 1;//error is here
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    for(i = 1; i < o; i++)
    {
        cout  << *row_b++ << ' ';
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, o;

    cin >> n;

    vector< vector< int > > map(n, vector< int >( n ));
    //filling up array in loop

    o = n * n;
    vector< int > row(n*n);

    vector< vector< int > >::iterator map_b = map.begin();
    vector< int >::iterator row_b = row.begin();
    displayArrays(map_b, row_b, n, o);
}
```

[Error] no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::vector' and 'int')

Comment: Passing an iterator is odd.  Just pass a const reference to the whole array.

Comment: Also don't use "jagged arrays" (vector < vector < T > >) for 2d matrix things.  Use an existing matrix library, or do your own indexing into a contiguous buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        cout << (*map_b)[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
    map_b++;
}
```